# Yet another Unicode preg_replace() question

Tags: php, unicode-string

I've read many posts that explain how to deal with Unicode characters, but none of the suggestions are working for me.

My php page reads a file that contains strings with high-order characters, e.g., "Mötor". I want to convert the strings to "normal" characters, e.g., "Motor".

This is what I have tried:

```
$source = "Mötor";
$test = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\p{L}]/u', "", $source); // Returns null.
$test = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\p{L}]/u', "", htmlentities($source)); // Returns "".
$test = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", $source); // Returns "Mötor".
$test = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($source)); // Returns "".
$test = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $source); // Returns false.
```

I am stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Are you confident that your input file is in UTF-8, and not some other encoding - either a different encoding of Unicode such as UTF-16, or one of the hundreds of non-Unicode encodings such as Windows-1252?

Comment: Also, make sure you have PHP errors displayed, or check your logs - the function calls that return false and null are probably also issuing a Warning that might provide additional clues to the problem.

Comment: Why do you assume that the text is ascii encoded?

Comment: what is interesting, `preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($source));` however barbaric it is, is giving me a correct result. and iconv gives M?tor. I suppose your input is not utf-8. Still I wish to know what's wrong with iconv.

Comment: @IMSop (and arkaschagood, although I can only reference one other user in a comment) figured it out. Notepad shows the file as ANSI format (which I've read means nothing), but resaving it in UTF-8 solved my problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Different systems may have wildly diferent implementations of `iconv`. In some cases, modes like `//TRANSLIT` are simply not implemented; in others, they will have different rules implemented. That's because [the POSIX standard specifies that an `iconv` function should exist](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html), but very little about how it should work, and specifically ["Settings of fromcode and tocode and their permitted combinations are implementation-defined."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv_open.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is called "transliteration" and intl's [Transliterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) will work *far* better than bodging together regular expressions.

```
$tests = [ "Mötor" ];

$tl = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');
foreach($tests as $str) {
    var_dump(
        $tl->transliterate($str)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "Motor"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it requires that the Transliterator extension has been installed which isn't the case on the server I am required to use.

Comment: You should lobby to have the intl extension installed, it has a _vast_ number of very useful functions for internationalization and utf-8

Answer (score 0):

A well proven way:

```
<?php
$source = "Mötor, šeřík, Προϊστορία, Україна";
var_dump( $source);
var_dump( preg_replace("/\p{Mn}/u", '',
            Normalizer::normalize( $source, Normalizer::FORM_D )));
?>
```

**Output**: `.\SO\76446827.php`

> ```
> string(54) "Mötor, šeřík, Προϊστορία, Україна"
> string(50) "Motor, serik, Προιστορια, Украіна"
> ```

## **Resources** (required reading):

- [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://Unicode%20Normalization%20Forms)
- Regular expressions: [Unicode Categories](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category)

  - `\p{M}` or `\p{Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).
    - `\p{Mn}` or `\p{Non_Spacing_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character without taking up extra space (e.g. **accents**, **umlauts**, etc.).

    - `\p{Mc}` or `\p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character that takes up extra space (vowel signs in many Eastern languages).
    - `\p{Me}` or `\p{Enclosing_Mark}`: a character that encloses the character it is combined with (circle, square, keycap, etc.).
- PHP manual: [Unicode character properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) (**note `/u` option for Unicode support in regex**)

**Note**: test string contains accented characters of various scripts (both *Western* and *Eastern Latin*, *Greek*, and *Cyrillic*) to demonstrate *script-independency* of used regex:

- `ö` (U+00F6,  *Latin Small Letter O With Diaeresis*)
- `š` (U+0161,  *Latin Small Letter S With Caron*)
- `ř` (U+0159,  *Latin Small Letter R With Caron*)
- `í` (U+00ED,  *Latin Small Letter I With Acute*)
- `ϊ` (U+03CA,  *Greek Small Letter Iota With Dialytika*)
- `ί` (U+03AF,  *Greek Small Letter Iota With Tonos*)
- `ї` (U+0457,  *Cyrillic Small Letter Yi*)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to resave the file (using Notepad) while specifying UTF-8.

Per comments by others, another solution would be to use Transliterator. However, that is a php extension which isn't installed on the (shared) server I am using.